# Reducing Memory requirements for distance/adjacency matrix

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, word-embedding

Based on a subsample of around 5,000 to 100,000 word-embeddings (GloVe, 300-dimensional) I need to construct an adjancency matrix, i.e. a matrix of 1's and 0's indicating if the euclidean (or cosine) distance between two words is smaller than `x`.

Currently, I'm using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`:

```
distances = pdist(common_model, 'euclidean')
adjacency = (distances <= 0.4)
adjacency = csr_matrix(squareform(adjacency), dtype=np.uint8)
```

With increasing vocabulary size, my memory fills up rather quickly and `pdist` fails with a `MemoryError` (when `common_model` has the shape `(91938, 300)` and contains `float64`).

Iterating the model manually and creating the adjacency directly without the distance matrix in between would be a way, but that was extremely slow.

Is there another way to construct the adjacency matrix in a time- and memory-optimal way?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  How large an input array can you use without it failing?  What is the `dtype` and `shape` of `common_model` when it fails?

Comment: I have 16 GB RAM on Win10 (64bit). `common_model.shape: (91938, 300)`, `common_model.dtype: float64`. I might reduce this through using `single`, but a solution that scales well would be preferred.

Comment: I ran it with shape=(9198, 300), float64 on my lame 4 GB RAM laptop and it worked fine.  How large can you go before it fails?  Try also `distances 
 = np.empty(..., dtype='f4'); pdist(x, out=distances)` to get 32-bit output without modifying your inputs--this should be a no-brainer because all you do is compare with 0.4 anyway, no need for double precision `distances`.  It would also help if you show your code for the iteration-based solution.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: You may have missed a digit (9198 vs 91938). 9198 items would result in about 645MiB while 91938 mean  64GiB. Using a pre-initialized array didn't work, because `pdist` expects a `double` type: `ValueError: Output array must be double type.`

Comment: I did use 1/10th the size on purpose.  I knew I didn't have enough RAM (or patience) to do the full size on my small laptop.  Would you consider a solution using Numba?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Based [on this example](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/15/numba-vs-cython-take-2/) I gave numba a try. Memory seems - for now - to be less of a problem and it is much faster than the pure python version I had before. Thanks for the hint!